# Summing estimated probabilities in classification model

Tags: probability, classification, predictive-models

I am developing a series of predictive classification models (decision trees, neural networks, etc.) aimed at predicting the number of people who enroll in a program based on a variety of demographic and pre-enrollment behavioral variables. The interest is in predicting the size of the incoming class.

The models I'm developing have admirably low misclassification rates (often < 2%) but those misclassifications are heavily skewed toward false positives, with usually at least twice as many (and sometimes more) FPs than false negatives.

In each case, the sum of the estimated classification probabilities gets close to the actual count of the events in the training data, even though the sum of classifications winds up a bit bonkers.

Since I'm actually only interested in predicting the sum total of enrollees (and some breakdowns by, e.g., residency, ethnicity, etc.), and not actually predicting any particular person's enrollment, is there any problem with fitting a classification model to a new data set and using the sum of the probabilities, rather than the sum of the classifications, to estimate this? My suspicion is that this will bias the ultimate answer toward the enrollment numbers of previous years, but I don't know for sure.